# How do I breed a Jade dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

Contrary to expectation, there's been a new gemstone dragon released, the Jade dragon. What's the combination with the highest success rate to get this dragon? I've so far been unable to find a confirmed breeding pair via my usual sources.

Comment: This is one of the longest times we've collectively gone without knowing...  we're still in the dark today even!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct pairing is [**Plasma + Salamander**](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/how-do-i-breed-a-jade-dragon-in-dragonvale/).  It took longer than usual to find since the use of opposite dragons (Plasma) was unexpected. Since this is a Gemstone dragon, there is only one valid combo.

Answer (score -3):

I have seen brass and seaweed but don't have proof myself.